VB.NET Unable to return a list based on unique values
Using VB.NET, I receive a list of objects. From this object list I need to clear out duplicate data sets so that the list is unique based on all columns. Reading around on StackOverflow, the general idea is to use GroupBy followed by Select however whenever I attempt to do this, the whole collection is returned still.
For this given example, I'd expect the count in uniqueData to be 3 but it remains at 4. dataSet1 and dataSet2 should be seen as a duplicate of each other
Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim data As New PersonCollection With {.PersonCollection = New List(Of PersonInfo)}
        Dim dataSet1 As New PersonInfo With {.FirstName = "Bob", .LastName = "Smith", .Rating = 10}
        Dim dataSet2 As New PersonInfo With {.FirstName = "John", .LastName = "Hurt", .Rating = 20}
        Dim dataSet3 As New PersonInfo With {.FirstName = "Bob", .LastName = "Smith", .Rating = 30}
        Dim dataSet4 As New PersonInfo With {.FirstName = "Bob", .LastName = "Smith", .Rating = 10}
        data.PersonCollection.Add(dataSet1)
        data.PersonCollection.Add(dataSet2)
        data.PersonCollection.Add(dataSet3)
        data.PersonCollection.Add(dataSet4)

        Dim uniqueData = data.PersonCollection.GroupBy(Function(x) New With {x.FirstName, x.LastName, x.Rating}).Select(Function(x) x.First).ToList()

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub


    Private Class PersonCollection
        Property PersonCollection As List(Of PersonInfo)
    End Class

    Private Class PersonInfo
        Property FirstName As String
        Property LastName As String
        Property Rating As Integer
    End Class
End Module


Try using a tuple instead, because it has value semantics as opposed to the anonymous class type which has reference semantics. .GroupBy((x.FirstName, x.LastName, x.Rating))

Does the code receive a List(Of Object) or does it receive some data over time? If the latter, maybe you could check if a new datum is already in the local data and if so then not add it.

It works with tuples:
Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim data As New PersonCollection With {.PersonCollection = New List(Of PersonInfo)}
        Dim dataSet1 As New PersonInfo With {.FirstName = "Bob", .LastName = "Smith", .Rating = 10}
        Dim dataSet2 As New PersonInfo With {.FirstName = "John", .LastName = "Hurt", .Rating = 20}
        Dim dataSet3 As New PersonInfo With {.FirstName = "Bob", .LastName = "Smith", .Rating = 30}
        Dim dataSet4 As New PersonInfo With {.FirstName = "Bob", .LastName = "Smith", .Rating = 10}
        data.PersonCollection.Add(dataSet1)
        data.PersonCollection.Add(dataSet2)
        data.PersonCollection.Add(dataSet3)
        data.PersonCollection.Add(dataSet4)

        Dim uniqueData = data.PersonCollection _
            .GroupBy(Function(x) New Tuple(Of String, String, Integer)(
                x.FirstName, x.LastName, x.Rating)) _
            .Select(Function(x) x.First).ToList()
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub


    Private Class PersonCollection
        Property PersonCollection As List(Of PersonInfo)
    End Class

    Private Class PersonInfo
        Property FirstName As String
        Property LastName As String
        Property Rating As Integer
    End Class
End Module

But it is better to use a Comparer:
Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim data As New PersonCollection With {.PersonCollection = New List(Of PersonInfo)}
        Dim dataSet1 As New PersonInfo With {.FirstName = "Bob", .LastName = "Smith", .Rating = 10}
        Dim dataSet2 As New PersonInfo With {.FirstName = "John", .LastName = "Hurt", .Rating = 20}
        Dim dataSet3 As New PersonInfo With {.FirstName = "Bob", .LastName = "Smith", .Rating = 30}
        Dim dataSet4 As New PersonInfo With {.FirstName = "Bob", .LastName = "Smith", .Rating = 10}
        data.PersonCollection.Add(dataSet1)
        data.PersonCollection.Add(dataSet2)
        data.PersonCollection.Add(dataSet3)
        data.PersonCollection.Add(dataSet4)

        Dim comparer As New PersonInfoComparer
        Dim uniqueData = data.PersonCollection.Distinct(comparer).ToList

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Class PersonCollection
        Property PersonCollection As List(Of PersonInfo)
    End Class

    Private Class PersonInfo
        Property FirstName As String
        Property LastName As String
        Property Rating As Integer
    End Class

    Private Class PersonInfoComparer : Inherits EqualityComparer(Of PersonInfo)

        Public Overrides Function Equals(x As PersonInfo, y As PersonInfo) As Boolean
            Return x.FirstName.Equals(y.FirstName) _
                AndAlso x.LastName.Equals(y.LastName) _
                AndAlso x.Rating.Equals(y.Rating)
        End Function

        Public Overrides Function GetHashCode(obj As PersonInfo) As Integer
#If NETSTANDARD2_0_OR_GREATER Or NETCOREAPP2_1_OR_GREATER Then
            Return HashCode.Combine(obj.FirstName, obj.LastName, obj.Rating)
#Else
            Return obj.FirstName.GetHashCode() _
                Xor obj.LastName.GetHashCode() _
                Xor obj.Rating.GetHashCode()
#End If
        End Function

    End Class

End Module


Also, if it's for .NET-later-than-Core-2-1, HashCode.Combine Method. Which I didn't know about until I wondered thinking about this answer.

@AndrewMorton, Thank you so much! I just learned about this method from you.

You're welcome :) But it would be better to add a mention of the "if it's for .NET-later-than-Core-2-1" in your answer, at least as a comment in the code. There are many people still using .NET Framework, so it would be good to show the version for that, perhaps as a comment in the text after the main answer.

@AndrewMorton, I would appreciate it if you could tell me if I applied the preprocessor directive correctly.

ah so for me I'm using .NET Framework. I should have specified sorry.

@Aiden, I checked as much as I could. It should work with #if directive.

thanks @KonstantinMakarov - I'll try with the tuple as I want to also extend this to a list of addresses that will reside within personInfo as Property addresses  as list(of personAddress)

If PersonCollection contains a lot of elements, then the correct implementation of GetHashCode function will be justified.

@KonstantinMakarov It's probably in excess of usual coding to worry about a preprocessor directive like that. Simply make sure that whoever is reading your answer is aware that there is a better method available. IMHO.

Try using a tuple instead, because it has value semantics as opposed to the anonymous class type which has reference semantics. I.e., two objects are compared by reference, not by their fields or properties.
.GroupBy(Function(x) (x.FirstName, x.LastName, x.Rating))

Note that the syntax New With {x.FirstName ... } does work with an O/R mapper, because then this is translated to SQL and the distinction between value and reference semantics does not apply anymore.

Another solution is to declare the properties of the anonymous type as Key Properties, then the key values will be compared.
.GroupBy(Function(x) New With {Key x.FirstName, Key x.LastName, Key x.Rating})

But tuples are so much easier.

We can slightly simplify the query by using DistinctBy instead of GroupBy followed by Select:
Dim uniqueData = data.PersonCollection _
    .DistinctBy(Function(x) (x.FirstName, x.LastName, x.Rating)) _
    .ToList()

Note also that the .ToList() is not necessary if you are enumerating the result afterwards, e.g., with For Each.
